# strpos function to check domain and ip

Tags: php

What is wrong here:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip; // 217.16.137.74

if (strpos($url, 'localhost') == true || strpos($ip, '217.16.') == true) {
   return;
}else{
   write();
}
```

So I'm on a remote server and my ip is `217.16.137.74`.
The above script is not canceled as expected, but `write()` function is executed.

Comment: `strpos` can not return true.

Comment: `strpos` will return `0` (which, when compared loosely, will evaluate false) since that's the position of of the first matching character, you need to do a strict comparison (ie. `!== false`)

Comment: Reading the manual would have helped. "Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."

Comment: if something is not false, than it's true, isn't it?

Comment: no, type juggling occurs when doing comparisons without explicitly comparing types, the manual will explain better than i'm able to - http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple reading of the manual would have answered this.

Comment: I think you need to change this: '$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";'  into this: '$url = "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/{$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]}";'.  You need curly braces around the 2 $_SERVER[] so PHP can tell them apart and you might need the '/' in between.

Comment: @PatrickQ, you'll find 90% SO answers on php manual.

Comment: @bonaca And I VTC probably close to 90% of the questions I look at

Comment: @PatrickQ, we are not all so smart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
strpos($ip, '217.16.') !== false
```

Using strict comparison `!==`

The above check if the searched string (*needle*) is **not present** in `$ip` (*stack*).

---

**Why you code fails:**

`strpos` returns the position (0-based) of the text searched, `false` if the text is not found.

As `$ip` begins with `217.16.` then `strpos` returns `0` that is considered equal to `false` when using loose comparison `==`